# AngularJS include without outer html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

In angular js is it possible to include something without adding extra html.

I used

```
<div ng-include>...</div>
```

but I don't really need that div in html.

Comment: A div is a simple block-element in html, which group other elements. So if you include other html elements in that div, its just a container around. Without any style information it does not influence the design of the page. Cant see a problem here.

Comment: You could write your own ng-include-like directive, so you could write something like `<my-dir="partial/to/include.html'></my-dir>`, but is that any better?  I like what @tschiela said (+1).

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/angularjs-ng-include)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what is wrong with creating a `<div>` to contain your `ng-include`. All it will do is provide the element for the `ng-include` to bind against allowing you to use the `ngInclude` directive.

As @mark-rajcok said in his comment, you could create your own Angular Directive but this would be even heavier on your page and requires unnecessary code. Much better to stick with using the element.