# AngularJS ui-router and ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I got my header in a header.html template file. I want to include it in my index.html with:

```
<div ui-view="header"></div>
```

After doing this, i still get this div around my header tag. Is it possible to use ui-view like include in php? I just want to include my header on this place, without this div.

And i know that i can place there direct the header tag. But then is the header template "inclomplete" it feels ugly and dirty.

Comment: Have you tried with `<div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>` ?

Comment: No. because i use the ui router and i use nested routings.

Comment: No this is not possible. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148988/replace-ui-view-with-the-loaded-content).

Answer (score 1):

Look to the [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) directive.