# AngularJS Directive property: Replace deprecated - Equivalent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So `AngularJs` are deprecating the `Replace` property of a directive. [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-i-e-v2-0-)

context:

```
  .directive('myDir', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div>{{title}}</div>'
    }
  });
```

this will ouput:

```
<my-dir>
   <div> some title </div>
</my-dir>
```

So, `Replace` would replace `<my-dir></my-dir>` with the `template`. What is the equivalent these days? Or is it just to use a directive with `restrict: 'A'`.

I created this:

```
  .directive('myDir', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div>{{title}}</div>',
      link: link
    };

    function link(scope, iElem, IAttr, ctrl, transcludeFn) {
      var parent = iElem.parent();
      var contents = iElem.html();

      iElem.remove();

      parent.append($compile(contents)(scope));
    }
  });
```

which will output:

```
<div> some title </div>
```

Comment: What you've done will work fine, as I'm sure you're aware. Seeing as that is being deprecated in version 2.0, I really wouldn't worry about not using it for the moment as the differences between the two will be pretty significant. Also quick Google suggests that the docs are out of date, it is not being removed - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb#commitcomment-8124407

Comment: @DanielEdwards oh fair enough, good shout that! I might as well put that as the answer. Or you can

Comment: This is not exactly a duplicate but this question has a suitable answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496647/replace-ng-include-node-with-template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs appear to be outdated - `replace` for directives is not being removed.

[Source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb#commitcomment-8124407)

Answer (score 4):

Basic equivalent to `replace: true` is

```
app.directive('directive', function () {
  return {
    ...
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.replaceWith(element.contents());
    }
  };
});
```

However, there are side effects that you can easily spot. Bindings are still there but attributes from the directive won't be translated into the template.

Luckily, there is usually no reason for this unless conditional `replace` is required. `replace` is considered deprecated for Angular 2 as you already noticed (it doesn't fit into web components concepts) but is perfectly fine for 1.x.