# Simple ng-include not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Im playing with AngularJS for the first time, and im struggling to use ng-include for my headers and footer.

Here's my tree:

```
myApp
assets
   - CSS
   - js
        - controllers
        - vendor
             - angular.js
             - route.js
             ......
             ......
             ......
        main.js
pages
   - partials
        - structure
              header.html
              navigation.html
              footer.html
   index.html
   home.html
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>AngularJS Test</title>

    <script src="/assets/js/vendor/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/vendor/route.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/vendor/resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>          

        <div ng-include src="partials/structure/header.url"></div>
        <div ng-include src="partials/structure/navigation.url"></div>    

        <div id="view" ng-view></div>   

        <div ng-include src="partials/structure/footer.url"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]);


app.config(function($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider.when("/login", {
    templateUrl: "login.html",
    controller: "LoginController"
});

$routeProvider.when("/home", {
    templateUrl: "home.html",
    controller: "HomeController"
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home'});

});

app.controller("HomeController", function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Home";
});
```

**home.html**

```
<div>
<p>Welcome to the {{ title }} Page</p>
</div>
```

When i go on the home.html page, my header, nav and footer are not appearing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/angularjs-ng-include)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You're doing an include of header.**url** instead of header.**html**. It looks like you want to use literals in the src attribute, so you should wrap them in quotes, as was mentioned in the comments by @DRiFTy.

Change

```
 <div ng-include src="partials/structure/header.url"></div>
 <div ng-include src="partials/structure/navigation.url"></div>    

 <div id="view" ng-view></div>   

 <div ng-include src="partials/structure/footer.url"></div>
```

to

```
 <div ng-include src="'partials/structure/header.html'"></div>
 <div ng-include src="'partials/structure/navigation.html'"></div>    

 <div id="view" ng-view></div>   

 <div ng-include src="'partials/structure/footer.html'"></div>
```

If this is not working, check the browser console if there are any 404's

Comment: To add to this, you need to wrap the path in single quotes: `src="'partials/structure/header.html'"`

Comment: Doh i forgot to check for 404's in the console. My path was wrong.

Comment: @DiscGolfer This is quite vital information. I checked my code for ages before this worked! +1

Comment: Can someone elaborate on why you must pass string literal? Seems like a major GOTCHA that could be avoided, perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: It's been this way at least since 1.0 (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/2430f52bb97fa9d682e5f028c977c5bf94c5ec38/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js) and I guess the authors thought it was more flexible to define it as an angular expression.

Comment: It's much more flexible. I've used it to embed function calls which generate the appropriate url on the fly.

Comment: My problem was that I was trying to use a relative path when it needs to be an absolute path, it is implies in this answer but not specifically stated.

Comment: If 404(File not found) occur, then we can use
    
       <ng-include src="'views/transaction/test.html'"></ng-include>

instead of,

        <div ng-include src = "'views/transaction/test.html'"></div>

Answer (score 100):

I had a similar problem with a simple ng-include not rendering:

`<div ng-include="views/footer.html"></div>`

I wrapped the file path in single quotes and it now renders:

`<div ng-include="'views/footer.html'"></div>`

Comment: I got this thing by hit and trial. But, still don't know what's the use of the ' inside " ? Why only " creates problems

Comment: Why does this happen?

Comment: You need to wrap string literals (e.g. your file path) with single quotes because anything within the full quotes will be evaluated as code, so without the single quotes, the Angular compiler will thing you have a function somewhere with the name of your file path.

Answer (score 18):

i had a similar problem that landed me here.

`ng-include` was not populating the contents of my partial, but there were no console errors, nor 404's.

then i realized what i did.

fix for me: make sure you have `ng-app` outside of the `ng-include`! so obvious. the price of being an Angular noob.

Comment: JEEZ, this is hard info to track down. I know that sounds ridiculous, but **so many** articles leave this part out. Even a couple "Hello World" tutorials didn't mention it. I took finding this answer then finding a working JSfiddle to learn I needed `<div ng-app>`. Absurd.

Comment: This one helped me out. Not even [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp) mention this.

Answer (score 2):

I also came across this issue. And this is what worked for me.

So instead of writing this:`<div ng-include="'html/form.htm'"></div>`

You want to add `ng-app=""`. So it should look like this: `<div ng-app="" ng-include="'html/form.htm'"></div>`

Comment: For the above answers, it was assumed that the ng-app is already applied and we are using ng-include inside it.

Comment: Better to add ng-app="myApp" to the opening <html> tag, but not to <div>

Comment: ...or in the body tag `<body ng-app="">`

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with the same issue and have done almost all what was advised in different stacks but it didn't work for me. On Console, I was getting the Error:

*"Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."*

Later I realised, I have to use a local web server (MAMP, WAMP etc.) to make it work.

Please be careful of the above error message. Chances are you are not using a local web server to run you website.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured this one out!

For me, I was using a CDN for importing my angular.min.js file that apparently wasn't working. I switched to:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>`

and included `ng-app=""` in my body tag:

```
<body ng-app="">
<div ng-include="'testfile.html'"></div>
```

and it's working fine now. Cheers!

Comment: No, that doesn't work on IE11 and Chrome. Only works on FF.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, without the `''`, ng would try to evaluate the contents inside the `ng-include("")`

This evaluation is another reason why you don't put `{{}}` inside these directives.

Answer (score 1):

ng-include is not working in chrome as well as in explorer but works in Firefox, so this could be compatibility issues. To be sure, try generating the report in Firefox or Edge or another browser.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: It's true that chrome browser known for its overpreventive policies blocks scripts to call pages from File:// origin this is why you can't render angular partials in chrome. neverthless this is right assumption and can take part of the multiplicity of causes that are possible to thwart the functioning of ng-view/ng-include.

Answer (score 0):

I Too had similar issue: Silly mistake was causing IT , I had below textArea
EG:

```
<textarea cols="3" type="text" id="WarehouseAddress"  class="form-control" > `
```

Wasn't closed properly Corrected below :

```
<textarea cols="3" type="text" id="WarehouseAddress"  class="form-control" ></textarea> 

<div ng-switch="vm.frmDOA.isGenerateDebitNote">
                <ng-include src="vm.showupload()"></ng-include>
            </div>
```

Thought to post it may help any one I digged hours to solve ....

Answer (score 0):

the ng-include file works for files fetched from the web server only (needs something like http://mywebsite/myinclude.html link). 
It does not work if you fetch file from local folder directly (c:\myinclude.html will not work)

Answer (score -1):

The **ng-include** directive should just work normal if you're viewing your file via some **server (localhost or online)** and **NOT** viewing your file directly **under file system** like (file:///yourpath/index.html).

[This example from w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_includes.asp) should work fine.