# ng-include with ion-nav-bar not displaying

Tags: angularjs

I'm running into an issue with using ng-include in ion-nav-bar. The ng-include(d) ion-nav-bar code isn't displaying (it is included though).

The code is as follows:

```
<ion-view title="test">
    <ng-include src="'partials/header-list.html'"></ng-include>
    <ion-content padding="false">Test</ion-content>
    <ng-include src="'partials/footer-badges.html'"></ng-include>
</ion-view>
```

The contents of partials/header-list.html is:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button button-clear ion-chevron-left"> Back </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-buttons side="right"><a href="#/app/home" class="button button-clear"> Home </a></ion-nav-buttons>
```

This is rendered into:

```
<ng-include src="'partials/header-list.html'" class=""><ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive bar bar-header nav-bar nav-title-slide-ios disable-user-behavior  invisible">
<ion-nav-back-button class="button button-clear back-button ng-hide"> Back </ion-nav-back-button>
<div class="buttons left-buttons"> </div><h1 ng-bind-html="title" class="title ng-binding"></h1>
<div class="buttons right-buttons"> <span class=""><a href="#/app/home" class="button button-clear"> Home </a></span></div></ion-nav-bar>
<ion-nav-buttons side="right" style="display: none;"></ion-nav-buttons></ng-include>
```

I can see that ion-nav-bar is set to class=invisible and ion-navs-buttons is set to display:none.

Why is this happening and what can I do to get the nav bar to display when used in ng-include?

Thanks
Meint

Answer (score 1):

As requested by [ArtOfCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3160466/artofcode) please find the full code below. The approach I've taken also correlates with the advice of the Ionic team given in the ["Navigating Ionic's Headers"](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-bar-vs-header-bar/) formula.

I'm using `<ion-nav-bar>` for the generic navigation and apply exceptions to that navigation via a specific `<ion-header-bar>`. An example of this approach:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">

  <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-dark">
    <div class="buttons">
      <a class="button button-icon icon ion-chevron-left" ng-href="#/app/group"> Back</a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="title"></h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a class="button button-icon icon ionic-plus" ng-href="#/app/member-create/{{groupid}}"></a>
      <a class="button button-icon icon ionic-minus" ng-href="#/app/member-delete"></a>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content class="has-header">
  </ion-content>

</ion-view>
```

As an additional remark I would like to add that I have found that angular directives provide a much better approach for reusability than using ng-include as originally envisioned by myself. All part of the leaning experience :-)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you want the inner single quotes in your src attribute

```
<ng-include src="partials/header-list.html" class="">...
```

Comment: yes, that's required, see [angularjs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) and this [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/angularjs-ng-include)

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon the same problem. Beta14 should somehow alleviate the issue with new ways to override the navbar. Until then, I'm using:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true">
```

and using an `<ion-header-bar>` instead, which can be included without problems. Note it should be used for non-standard views.

An example:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class='title'>
            Hello!
        </h1>
   </ion-header-bar>

   <ion-content class="has-header">
        Content
   </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: You might want to post the full set of code you've used... where does the `<ion-header-bar>` go?