# AngularJS Error Unterminated

Tags: angularjs

Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%205-6%20%5B%22%5D&p2=query%22

The line it is complaining about is:

```
<div ng-include=" 'templates/header.html' "></div>
```

I've tried:

```
<div ng-include="'templates/header.html'"></div>
<ng-include src=" 'templates/header.html' "></ng-include>
```

I don't get it, it looks right to me.

Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.9/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%205-6%20%5B%22%5D&p2=query%22
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:6:416
    at gc.throwError (http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:185:475)
    at gc.readString (http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:188:195)
    at gc.lex (http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:183:433)
    at hb.parse (http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:188:443)
    at $get (http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:111:7)
    at new cg (http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:220:57)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:37:96)
    at $get.z.instance (http://localhost:8080/js/angular.min.js:76:210)

Comment: Also see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/angularjs-ng-include

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me

```
 <div ng-include src="'templates/header.html'"></div>
```

Comment: It appears to be a problem with the actual header.html file itself.