# How to load the specific div class or id in to another html using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In jQuery, it is possible to load the specific selector element in another HTML using the classes and id on load function

For example: `$('#id').load("http://www.thisiswhyimbroke.com li:first .someclass")`

Is there any way to do the same in AngularJS include i.e ng-include?

Comment: Yes there is same directive which is you defined in question

Comment: ng-include= " '//url of your template' "

Answer (score 1):

```
try this..
<div class="include-example" ng-class="template.class" ng-include="template.url">
```

Comment: Mahesh:  -  i want to include <div class="preloader">, construct from detail.html to base.html bottom: <div class="preloader-include" ng-class="detail.html" ng-include="details.html"></div> is that right ? that is i want to get the part of html(only preloader html construct)  from details.html to include on base.html.

Comment: Refer this link  -look example    https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Answer (score 1):

Yes! I figured this out today. In my case I'm loading from the same domain, but loading in the entire page (angular, bootstrap, etc) just wasn't going to work.

In short you're going to need to make an interceptor catch the response and process it.

First, point your ng-include to your url.

```
<div ng-include="currentView.content.url"></div>
```

Second, we'll need to intercept the response. In my case I know I will always be loading in #articleAnswer.

```
app.factory('templateInterceptor', function($q) {
return {
    response: function( response ) {
        var html = response.data.toString();
        if (html.indexOf('articleAnswer') !== -1) {  
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var doc = parser.parseFromString(html,'text/html');
            var article = doc.querySelectorAll('#articleAnswer');
            response.data = article;
        }
        return response;
    }   
};
});
```

Third, add the factory you just made to your $httpProvider interceptors.

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('templateInterceptor');
});
```

Fourth, you'll probably also want this bit in place to allow you to load in trusted html.

```
app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self']); 
});
```

I'm sure someone has a more elegant way of doing this, but hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

yes angular have directive for include templates in another html

please check these examples
    `http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/mfha6/`

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/9krVn/3/`
```

both examples are fruitfull for ng-include and also get help from this question  [What is the correct syntax of ng-include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/angularjs-ng-include)