# Embedding Html page using Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to Angular js and I'm trying to use Angular js to embed html snippets within a html page with the help of bootstrap template.

This is my index.html

```
<body >
  <div ng-app="">
     <div ng-include="mainmenu.html"></div>


       <!-- Page Content -->
          <div class="container">

         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
               <h1>Starter Template</h1>
                <p class="lead">Complete with pre-defined file paths that you won't have to change!</p>

           </div>
         </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    </div>
<!-- /.container -->
 </div>
  <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.1 -->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

  <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my manimenu.html

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Both index.html and mainmenu.html are in same folder. But mainmenu.html is not showing inside the index.html. If anyone knows please help me to solve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.try with this or checkout the link below

```
<div ng-include src="'mainmenu.html'"></div>

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/angularjs-ng-include
```

Answer (score 5):

All you're missing is quotes around the reference to your template. Without quotes, it's evaluated as an expression.

```
<div ng-include="'mainmenu.html'"></div>
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

**angular expression evaluating to URL. If the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in single quotes, e.g. src="'myPartialTemplate.html'".**