# Ng-include in IE 11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm in IE 11 working with Angular and I have an span containing an icon that I'm trying to include via the following.

```
<ng-include
popover="popover"
class="input-group-addon popover-icon-warning"
role="button"
data-toggle="popover"
data-trigger="focus"
src="config.warningIconSVG"></ng-include>
```

Instead of the span coming in I get

```
<!-- ngInclude: -->
```

I've tried restructuring the ng-include, and adding the createElement to the javascript being loaded in but nothing works. Any answers or direction on where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In case you running this inside ng-if - you may be in isolated scope - so you may not see "config", if it is the case, try $parent.config

Comment: Did you try `src=" 'config.warningIconSVG' "`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/angularjs-ng-include

Comment: @gilango his source doesn't appear to be a static string but an expression. As such, putting quotes around it won't help.

Comment: @gilango that would make that url be the string value...doesn't make sense

Comment: Right before the `ng-include` try `{{config.warningIconSVG}}` and see if the url prints in view. Also probably not a good idea adding those other directives on `ng-include` and move them to the template

Comment: @Nosyara not inside an ng-if

Comment: I want to add it works perfectly inside of chrome.

Comment: Could you please create a plunkr for the same?

Comment: Also check in dev tools network at what happens to the request for the template

Comment: @gilango I tried adding the single quotes and I got an iFrame.