# uib-tabset not loading from external template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

version:ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js

I am facing issue in loading tabs defined in external html file. In index.html file I have referred the tab which is defined in the external template.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 no-padding" template="Scripts/tpl/optionTab.tpl.html" templateUrl="Scripts/tpl/optionTab.tpl.html" ></div>
```

I have following example code defined in file Scripts/tpl/optionTab.tpl.html

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
<uib-tab index="0" heading="Static title">Static content</uib-tab>
<uib-tab index="$index + 1" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" disable="tab.disabled">
  {{tab.content}}
</uib-tab>
<uib-tab index="3" select="alertMe()">
  <uib-tab-heading>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></i> Alert!
  </uib-tab-heading>
  I've got an HTML heading, and a select callback. Pretty cool!
</uib-tab>
```

The above code works fine if i add it directly into the index.html file i.e without referring the same from external template. Can anyone please guide as what is the issue here ? There is no error in console. 
i have tried template, templatUrl, ng-include but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting answer for my own question as it might help someone new to angular like me.

I can't believe that it was a very simple solution and no expert could helped to point in right direction. What all I wanted was to include the uib-tabset defined in external html file into the index.html. I tried the options of uib-tabset such as template-url(seem like it is bug as it is not picking the external file and throwing error such as multiple root elements etc). I tried ng-include but nothing seem to work. Shared plunker on request etc ultimatley I found that following is what all I needed in index.html to solve it.

```
 <div ng-include src="'Scripts/tpl/optionTab.tpl.html'"></div>
```

I was missing the single quote before the path and angular was not importing the partial html containing uib-tabset as it was trying to parse the path as variable. With single quote it treated as string and it worked. Thanks to post below which helped.

[What is the correct syntax of ng-include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/what-is-the-correct-syntax-of-ng-include)

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo. Use `template-url` attribute instead of `templateUrl`.

```
template-url="Scripts/tpl/optionTab.tpl.html"
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/GxGXdWy4d5a8sD44RLu9?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry but that did not worked. I already tried that template-url for uib-tab. In addition to that I tried loading external template using templateUrl on a div. There is no error being thrown in console. However if I modify the optionTab.tpl.html and add some invalid data in it (such as text 'rr' before  <uib-tab  ng-repeat=.. ) then error comes in console. So template is being picked but not getting display

Comment: Can you please reproduce your problem in plunker please?

Comment: please try the plunker link now. TO me it is giving same response as I mentioned. I am sure I am missing something but it is coming consistently.

Comment: please find it here https://plnkr.co/edit/jUiMkIUnM5ue6A9MIlbE?p=preview

Comment: I updated the plunker yesterday. if you have got chance to look it then can you comment if the code in template file is defined incorrectly ? I have taken the sample code only. Is it not able to find the controller if uib-tab defined in external file ?