# how to force reload using ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm using

```
<div ng-include = "myController.myVar">.
```

During the flow of my program, myController.myVar a string generated by the return of a function.

Example:

```
myController.myVar = MyFunction ();
```

Although the value of myController.myVar has been properly updated, ng-include does not render the new value.

Here's a new example. (Although it's simple, the actual application is a bit more complex). Basically it is something as described below:

We have an ng-include to render some pages.

In the controller we have a function very similar to this:

```
var myFunction = function (index) {
     return [
"path1",
"path2",
"path3"
][index];
};

Follow the flow:

// Start MyController.MyVar
this.MyVar = myFunction (0);

// An HTTP request is made and, if the return is as expected, then the value of myVar is updated.

if (request === 'success') {
      this.myVar = MyFunction (1);
}
```

However, ng-include does not seem to recognize the new MyVar value in the view and does not reload the new value.

Comment: Are we to ignore the typos in the function names?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, please ignore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct syntax of ng-include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/what-is-the-correct-syntax-of-ng-include)

Comment: @RandyCasburn It is not duplicate.

Comment: Let's go with that for a moment - will you at least closely read the other answer so that you can fix your problem?